# PIC 16F628 CC5X Structure

Tags: c, pic

I Use CC5X compiler.
I write a ham radio parrot for speech  and morse with a 16F628 PIC.
My program works fine from A to 9 (128 - or .) but don't works after 9 to end.
I know this must be a size of pointer problem, but can't solve it.
I put -mc2 to assign 16 bits pointers to const access, but it is the same.
If you have an advice.

I have a struct for morse code :

```
static const struct {
    const uns8 letter;
    const uns8 code[6];
}
MorseMap[] =
{
    { 'A', ".-" },
    { 'B', "-..." },
    { 'C', "-.-." },
    { 'D', "-.." },
    { 'E', "." },
    { 'F', "..-." },
    { 'G', "--." },
    { 'H', "...." },
    { 'I', ".." },
    { 'J', ".---" },
    { 'K', ".-.-" },
    { 'L', ".-.." },
    { 'M', "--" },
    { 'N', "-." },
    { 'O', "---" },
    { 'P', ".--." },
    { 'Q', "--.-" },
    { 'R', ".-." },
    { 'S', "..." },
    { 'T', "-" },
    { 'U', "..-" },
    { 'V', "...-" },
    { 'W', ".--" },
    { 'X', "-..-" },
    { 'Y', "-.--" },
    { 'Z', "--.." },
    { ' ', "x" }, // 

    { '1', ".----" },
    { '2', "..---" },
    { '3', "...--" },
    { '4', "....-" },
    { '5', "....." },
    { '6', "-...." },
    { '7', "--..." },
    { '8', "---.." },
    { '9', "----." }, // 128  car . and - OK to here
    { '0', "-----" }, // Here starts the bug

    { ',', "--..--" },
    { '?', "..--.." },
    { '!', "-.-.--" },
    { ':', "---..." },
    { ';', "-.-.-." },
    { '(', "-.--." },
    { ')', "-.--.-" },
    { '"', ".-..-." },
    { '@', ".--.-." },
    { '&', ".-..." },
    { '.', "·–·–·–" },
};

uns8 *j;    // my pointer to the structure

/*And a function to associate the code
void encode(uns8 lettre)     // encode la lettre à envoyer en morse*/
{
    uns8 a;
    for(j = 0; j < 46; j++)
    {
        a = MorseMap[j].letter;
        if(lettre == a)
        {
            code_morse[0] = MorseMap[j].code[0];
            code_morse[1] = MorseMap[j].code[1];
            code_morse[2] = MorseMap[j].code[2];
            code_morse[3] = MorseMap[j].code[3];
            code_morse[4] = MorseMap[j].code[4];
            code_morse[5] = MorseMap[j].code[5];
            code_morse[6] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the code is ok for 0 also.

Comment: Just removed my answer as it seems wrong.. How `code_morse` is defined?

Comment: Not knowing about CC5X, compareing pointer `j` to integer `46` is bad in normal C.

Comment: I guess it may be not number of `-` and `.` but total number of data bytes exceeding 256 that causes the problem.

Comment: Also, If it is encoded in UTF-8, `"·–·–·–"`, mapped to `.`, exceed 6 bytes and causes compile error.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the code with a few modification with CC5X Version 3.5C FREE edition with option `-a -mc2 -p16F628`, and saw that `ADDWF` is used to calculate the offset from index for `MorseMap` like this:

```
                        ;    {
                        ;        a = MorseMap[j].letter;
        CLRF  ci+1
        MOVF  j,W
        MOVWF ci
        ADDWF ci,W
        ADDWF ci,1
        ADDWF ci,1
        ADDWF ci,1
        CALL  _const1
        BCF   0x03,RP0
        BCF   0x03,RP1
        MOVWF a
```

This will cause overflow (wrap) when the offset exceeds 256, and it will happen on 36th element (0-origin) as each element consumes 7 bytes.

Also, when I changed the type of `j` to `uns8`, I got "Unable to generate code" error.

Splitting the table to two tables whose size are 256 bytes or less seems one of solutions to this.

```
static const struct MorseMapEntry {
    const uns8 letter;
    const uns8 code[6];
}
MorseMap0[] =
{
    { 'A', ".-" },
    { 'B', "-..." },
    { 'C', "-.-." },
    { 'D', "-.." },
    { 'E', "." },
    { 'F', "..-." },
    { 'G', "--." },
    { 'H', "...." },
    { 'I', ".." },
    { 'J', ".---" },
    { 'K', ".-.-" },
    { 'L', ".-.." },
    { 'M', "--" },
    { 'N', "-." },
    { 'O', "---" },
    { 'P', ".--." },
    { 'Q', "--.-" },
    { 'R', ".-." },
    { 'S', "..." },
    { 'T', "-" },
    { 'U', "..-" },
    { 'V', "...-" },
    { 'W', ".--" },
    { 'X', "-..-" },
    { 'Y', "-.--" },
    { 'Z', "--.." },
    { ' ', "x" }, // 

    { '1', ".----" },
    { '2', "..---" },
    { '3', "...--" },
    { '4', "....-" },
    { '5', "....." },
    { '6', "-...." },
    { '7', "--..." },
    { '8', "---.." },
    { '9', "----." }
};

static const struct MorseMapEntry MorseMap1[] =
{
    { '0', "-----" },

    { ',', "--..--" },
    { '?', "..--.." },
    { '!', "-.-.--" },
    { ':', "---..." },
    { ';', "-.-.-." },
    { '(', "-.--." },
    { ')', "-.--.-" },
    { '"', ".-..-." },
    { '@', ".--.-." },
    { '&', ".-..." },
    { '.', ".-.-.-" },
};

uns8 j;    // my pointer to the structure
uns8 code_morse[7]; // buffer to store the result

/*And a function to associate the code*/
void encode(uns8 lettre)     // encode la lettre à envoyer en morse
{
    uns8 a;
    for(j = 0; j < 36; j++)
    {
        a = MorseMap0[j].letter;
        if(lettre == a)
        {
            code_morse[0] = MorseMap0[j].code[0];
            code_morse[1] = MorseMap0[j].code[1];
            code_morse[2] = MorseMap0[j].code[2];
            code_morse[3] = MorseMap0[j].code[3];
            code_morse[4] = MorseMap0[j].code[4];
            code_morse[5] = MorseMap0[j].code[5];
            code_morse[6] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    // note: there are actually 48 elements in total, so 10 here should be 12 to scan all elements
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        a = MorseMap1[j].letter;
        if(lettre == a)
        {
            code_morse[0] = MorseMap1[j].code[0];
            code_morse[1] = MorseMap1[j].code[1];
            code_morse[2] = MorseMap1[j].code[2];
            code_morse[3] = MorseMap1[j].code[3];
            code_morse[4] = MorseMap1[j].code[4];
            code_morse[5] = MorseMap1[j].code[5];
            code_morse[6] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    encode('?');
    for(;;);
}
```

(compiled, but not tested)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is a size problem.  The structure declaration should be

```
struct MorseMapEntry{
    const uns8 letter;
    const uns8 code[7];
}
```

The first string after 0 is

```
{ ',', "--..--" },
```

which, including the null terminator is 7 characters.  You're only allocating 6.  This means that you will have to add the one extra character in the encoding too.